# New kitten not eating, threw up twice

Tags: cats, health, eating, junior-pets, new-pets

Just got 2 new kittens, and this is the first time I've had cats. One of the kittens isn't eating much and threw up twice (mostly spit than anything). Her poo was also a bit runny, but her brother also had that issue. Any advice? These kitties are under foster, just want to make sure they're all right before I head off to work tomorrow.

Comment: I'd suggest to at least phone the vet or nearest pet clinic that has 24h coverage right away, describe the kittens and situation and ask how to proceed. Quick advice on the phone is typically free, and will bring you peace of mind if nothing else.